Probability distribution of maximum of dependent binomial RVs
Suppose $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ are each $\mbox{Bin}(n,p)$ random variables but with the requirement that $\sum_{k=1}^m X_k=n$.
For instance, suppose we roll a fair $6$-sided die $n$ times, and $X_1$ counts the number of times that a one is rolled, $X_2$ counts the number of times that a two is rolled, etc. Clearly, each $X_k$ on its own is $\mbox{Bin}(n,1/6$), but we must also have $\sum_{k=1}^6 X_k=n$.
What is the distribution of $Y=\max(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$, that is, the frequency of the roll that occurred most often?
I tried considering some particular probabilities, but the combinatorics got messy very quickly.

Searching "multinomial distribution" may be more fruitful. Here and here are related questions.

@angryavian Yes uniform multinomial to be precise. Just found some papers on the maximum of a uniform multinomial which only confirmed my suspicion that it's a combinatorial mess.
